# Laravel 5.6 error on create token: There was an error while creating the signature: error:04075070:rsa routines:RSA_sign:digest too big for rsa key

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

When I try to create a token for an authenticated user via

$user->createToken('Somename')->accessToken;

it returns "There was an error while creating the signature: error:04075070:rsa routines:RSA_sign:digest too big for rsa key", so after search on google it seems to be a problem with openssl lib, but I don't know how to resolve this.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Passport v6.0.4. For work around you can downgrade passport to v6.0.3 and run this command again `php artisan passport:key`